# GET http://localhost:4200/account/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) in Angular 11

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my app-routing module

```
{path:'account',loadChildren:()=>import('./ApplicationUsers/account/account.module').then(mode=>mode.AccountModule)},
```

Here is account routing child module,

```
const routes:Routes=[
  {path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'register',component:RegisterComponent}
]
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ISMSAngular</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition  sidebar-mini layout-fixed layout-navbar-fixed layout-footer-fixed mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</html>
```

angular.json

```
"styles": [

              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.css",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.css",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.css",
              "node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/alertify.min.css",
              "node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/themes/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ,
              "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jquery/jquery.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",

              "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.js",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/adminlte.js",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/demo.js",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/raphael/raphael.js",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jquery-mapael/jquery.mapael.js",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/chart.js/Chart.js",
              "node_modules/admin-lte/dist/js/pages/dashboard2.js",
              "node_modules/alertifyjs/build/alertify.min.js"
            ]
```

Now when I run the application and route to `http://localhost:4200/account/login`
it throws the given error: GET http://localhost:4200/account/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This looks like a strange path: ./ApplicationUsers/account/account.module').then(mode=>mode.AccountModule - is that actually part of your application?